# cloud storage: how to check md5 on object

Tags: automation, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I have this scenarios happening in my bucket,  I have file called red.dat in my storage and this file will be updating regularly by jenkins once this file has been update I trigger event to deploy this red.dat file, I want check md5 hash of the file before and after update and if the value is different only do the deployment

this is how I upload the file to GCS

```
gsutil cp red.dat gs://example-bucket
```

and I have tried this command to get hash

```
gsutil hash -h gs://example-bucket/red.dat
```

and the result is this

```
Hashes [hex] for red.dat:
    Hash (crc32c):      d4c9895e
    Hash (md5):     732b9e36d945f31a6f436a8d19f64671
```

but I'm little confused how I can implement to compare md5 before and after update since the file is always gonna be stay remote location(GCS). I would like some advice or show me right direction to achieve this, solution in commands or ansible is fine

Answer (score 2):

You can use the gsutil hash command on the local file, and then compare the output with what you saw from gsutil hash against the cloud object:

```
gsutil hash red.dat
```